# How i do select an item from an object using linq or any other approach

Tags: c#, linq

I have two objects named Transactions and CreditorDetails . I want to be able to get the retrieve say CFirstName from my transations object. I don't want to retrieve it from CreditorDetails. for example, i want to be able to say

```
foreach ( Transactions item in info.transaction)
{
     Console.WriteLine("My Name" + item.creditors.Select(m =>m.CFirstName));//Just an example
}
```

The above code isn't giving me the desired result. it's returning system.linq.Enumerable+whereSelectListIterator........... which i think i know why but i need to be able to get the CFirstName from Transaction object.

```
class Transactions
{
     public List<CreditorsDetails> creditors { get; set; }
     //Contains some other things which i didn't bother inlude since they are irrelevant 
}

class CreditorsDetails 
{
     public string CFirstName { get; set; }
     public string CAddress { get; set; }
     public string CCountry { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: It would be awesome if you could provide a [mcve] which I could copy and paste into a console app and get up and running fast. Even better if it could include sample inputs and expected sample outputs.

Comment: If a foreign key established between Transaction and CreditorsDetails then you should use `Include` method to include related entities , More info : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj574232(v=vs.113).aspx#Anchor_0

Answer (score 0):

`Select` will give you an enumerable of `strings` you need to iterate that to access the information:

```
foreach (Transactions item in info.transaction)
{
    foreach (var cfName in item.creditors.Select(m => m.CFirstName))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My Name" + cfName);
    }
}
```

If you just want the first item in the list you can also use `FirstOrDefault`

```
foreach (Transactions item in info.transaction)
{
    Console.WriteLine("My Name" + item.creditors.Select(m => m.CFirstName).FirstOrDefault());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SelectMany` to retrieve items from sub-lists:

```
var result = info.transaction.SelectMany(x => x.creditors.Select(y => y.CFirstName));
```

The inner `Select` retrieves a list of the first names of the creditors of a transaction. By using `SelectMany`, you concatenate all lists of first names of all creditors in a single list.

If you want to return only distinct values, you can add a call to `Distinct`:

```
var result = info.transaction.SelectMany(x => x.creditors.Select(y => y.CFirstName))
               .Distinct();
```